# Auto adjust image in canvas, If image resolution is larger than canvas size in Html5

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, fabricjs

I am using Html5, fabric.js and Java script. I am uploading multiple images in canvas, But sometimes uploaded image larger than canvas. I want image set in fix size.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
document.getElementById('file').addEventListener("change", function (e) {
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (f) {
    var data = f.target.result;                    
    fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function (img) {
      var oImg = img.set({left: 50, top: 100, angle: 00}).scale(0.9);
      canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
      var a = canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
      var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({format: 'png', quality: 0.8});
      console.log("aaaaaaaaaaa" + dataURL);

      //                        console.log("Canvas Image " + dataURL);
      //                        document.getElementById('txt').href = dataURL;

    });
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});
document.querySelector('#txt').onclick = function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  canvas.deactivateAll().renderAll();
  document.querySelector('#preview').src = canvas.toDataURL();
}
```

```css
canvas{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="file">
<canvas id="canvas" width="750" height="550"></canvas>
<a href='' id='txt' target="_blank">Click Me!!</a>
<br />
<img id="preview" />
```

**Before upload:**

[image]

**After upload:**

[image]

I want every image to fix size. After uploading image, user can change the size, angle and other property.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, you can resize the image to the size you want by passing those parameters (`width` and `height`) to the function `img.set`.

```
img.set({... width:100, height:100});
```

**The full code:**

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
document.getElementById('file').addEventListener("change", function (e) {
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (f) {
    var data = f.target.result;                    
    fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function (img) {
      var oImg = img.set({left: 50, top: 100, angle: 00, width:100, height:100}).scale(0.9);
      canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
      var a = canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
      var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({format: 'png', quality: 0.8});
      console.log("aaaaaaaaaaa" + dataURL);

      //                        console.log("Canvas Image " + dataURL);
      //                        document.getElementById('txt').href = dataURL;

    });
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});
document.querySelector('#txt').onclick = function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  canvas.deactivateAll().renderAll();
  document.querySelector('#preview').src = canvas.toDataURL();
}
```

```css
canvas{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="file">
<canvas id="canvas" width="750" height="550"></canvas>
<a href='' id='txt' target="_blank">Click Me!!</a>
<br />
<img id="preview" />
```

Comment: Mind Blowing. You are genius.. Thanks again.

Comment: If you don't mind. I want to ask one question? How to write custom text on this image.

Comment: Sure. If it's about this question. If not, please ask a new question and paste her link here and I will see it. A new question will be helpful to other people with a similar problem.

Comment: ok. but i have no idea about custom text. But i will try and ask  the new question.

Comment: Please check this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34739645/write-custom-text-on-image-canvas-with-fabric-js-and-html5

Comment: Could you see this link.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47988896/how-to-add-time-picker-in-datepicker-html-javascript?noredirect=1#comment82946620_47988896

Answer (score 0):

add height and width of specific size in your code as below.

`var oImg = img.set({width: 150, height: 150, left: 50, top: 100, angle: 00}).scale(0.9);`