# Write custom text on image canvas with fabric.js and HTML5

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, fabricjs

I am using HTML5 and [`fabric.js`](http://fabricjs.com/) for uploading multiple images. I want to add custom text on this image canvas. Right now I am uploading multiple images into canvas one by one. After uploading images I want to add custom text on canvas.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
document.getElementById('file').addEventListener("change",function (e) {
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  console.log("reader   " + reader);
  reader.onload = function (f) {
    var data = f.target.result;
    fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function (img) {
      var oImg = img.set({left: 70, top: 100, width: 250, height: 200, angle: 0}).scale(0.9);
      canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
      var a = canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
      var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({format: 'png', quality: 0.8});
    });
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});
document.querySelector('#txt').onclick = function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  canvas.deactivateAll().renderAll();
  document.querySelector('#preview').src = canvas.toDataURL();
};
```

```css
canvas{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="file">
<canvas id="canvas" width="750" height="550"></canvas>
<a href='' id='txt' target="_blank">Click Me!!</a><br />
<img id="preview" />
```

https://jsfiddle.net/varunPes/vb1weL93/

I have seen some links:

- http://fancyproductdesigner.com/product/t-shirt/ - The expected result.
- http://jsfiddle.net/EffEPi/qpJTz/

**Update**

I need that the user can choose the text's `color` and the `font-family`.

After clicking on `Click Me!!` button, the `custom text` and image should come together in one image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`IText`](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.IText.html) like this:

```js
canvas.add(new fabric.IText('Tap and Type', {
  fontFamily: 'arial black',
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
}));
```

And the full code:

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

document.getElementById('file').addEventListener("change", function (e) {
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  console.log("reader   " + reader);
  reader.onload = function (f) {
    var data = f.target.result;
    fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function (img) {
      var oImg = img.set({left: 70, top: 100, width: 250, height: 200, angle: 0}).scale(0.9);
      canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
      canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);  
    });
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});

$('#fill').change(function(){
  var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();

  if(obj){
    // old api
    // obj.setFill($(this).val());
    obj.set("fill", this.value);
  }
  canvas.renderAll();
});

$('#font').change(function(){
  var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
  
  if(obj){
    // old api
    // obj.setFontFamily($(this).val());
    obj.set("fontFamily", this.value);
  }
  
  canvas.renderAll();
});

function addText() {
  var oText = new fabric.IText('Tap and Type', { 
    left: 100, 
    top: 100 ,
  });

  canvas.add(oText);
  oText.bringToFront();
  canvas.setActiveObject(oText);
  $('#fill, #font').trigger('change');
}

document.querySelector('#txt').onclick = function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  canvas.deactivateAll().renderAll();
  document.querySelector('#preview').src = canvas.toDataURL();
};
```

```css
canvas{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.3.6/fabric.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" id="file">
<input type="color" value="blue" id="fill" />
<select id="font">
  <option>arial</option>
  <option>tahoma</option>
  <option>times new roman</option>
</select>
<button onclick="addText()">Add Custom Text</button>
<br />
<canvas id="canvas" width="750" height="550"></canvas>
<a href='' id='txt' target="_blank">Click Me!!</a>
<br />
<img id="preview" />
```

**Update:**
To keep the text always in the front you need to use `.bringToFront()` function. 
(Thanks to @Amit Sharma in [Fabric.js - problem with drawing multiple images zindex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939782/fabric-js-problem-with-drawing-multiple-images-zindex))

http://jsbin.com/qicesa/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: I want to only one time custom text. In your code have multiple custom tag for multiple image. And i want text color, font style.

Comment: `one time custom text` Do you mean that the first time the user upload an image? `i want text color, font style` Do you mean that you want to control the color and the font? If so, see the snippet: `fontFamily: 'arial black',`. Also, read the doc about it (Click on `IText`)

Comment: You have anyother idea?

Comment: Because i want only text color and font-style choose by user.

Comment: your answer is correct. But when i upload next image then custom text will hide.Custom text should be above of all images

Comment: Yes it is correct. Can you add one more functionality. When click on button then show custom text area. button should be out side from canvas.

Comment: If you don't mind. Could you see this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47568013/get-more-than-1000-row-in-the-data-table-in-angular-js-from-mongodb

Comment: @Michel, I just updated my answer. The API is changed so I'm using the new API now. Don't worry, be happy :)