# How to add time picker in datepicker html javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angular-ui-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I am implementing datepicker but I want to add time picker also. Now I am selecting date and time separately. but I want to select date and time in sequence after one click.

I want to implement like this http://embed.plnkr.co/MtQK3wsHtf1hy1F9A5rg/ But I want to consider 24hrs clock. I don't want to use any directive. In plnkr using directive. I want using single javascript file.

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('DatepickerPopupDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.today = function() {
    $scope.dt = new Date();
  };
  $scope.today();

  $scope.clear = function() {
    $scope.dt = null;
  };

  $scope.inlineOptions = {
    customClass: getDayClass,
    minDate: new Date(),
    showWeeks: true
  };

  $scope.dateOptions = {
    dateDisabled: disabled,
    formatYear: 'yy',
    maxDate: new Date(2020, 5, 22),
    minDate: new Date(),
    startingDay: 1
  };

  // Disable weekend selection
  function disabled(data) {
    var date = data.date,
      mode = data.mode;
    return mode === 'day' && (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6);
  }

  $scope.toggleMin = function() {
    $scope.inlineOptions.minDate = $scope.inlineOptions.minDate ? null : new Date();
    $scope.dateOptions.minDate = $scope.inlineOptions.minDate;
  };

  $scope.toggleMin();

  $scope.open1 = function() {
    $scope.popup1.opened = true;
  };

  $scope.open2 = function() {
    $scope.popup2.opened = true;
  };

  $scope.setDate = function(year, month, day) {
    $scope.dt = new Date(year, month, day);
  };

  $scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
  $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];
  $scope.altInputFormats = ['M!/d!/yyyy'];

  $scope.popup1 = {
    opened: false
  };

  $scope.popup2 = {
    opened: false
  };

  var tomorrow = new Date();
  tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
  var afterTomorrow = new Date();
  afterTomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
  $scope.events = [
    {
      date: tomorrow,
      status: 'full'
    },
    {
      date: afterTomorrow,
      status: 'partially'
    }
  ];

  function getDayClass(data) {
    var date = data.date,
      mode = data.mode;
    if (mode === 'day') {
      var dayToCheck = new Date(date).setHours(0,0,0,0);

      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.events.length; i++) {
        var currentDay = new Date($scope.events[i].date).setHours(0,0,0,0);

        if (dayToCheck === currentDay) {
          return $scope.events[i].status;
        }
      }
    }

    return '';
  }
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<style>
  .full button span {
    background-color: limegreen;
    border-radius: 32px;
    color: black;
  }
  .partially button span {
    background-color: orange;
    border-radius: 32px;
    color: black;
  }
</style>
<div ng-controller="DatepickerPopupDemoCtrl">
  

    <h4>Popup</h4>
    <div class="row">
    

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup ng-model="dt" is-open="popup2.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open2()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
          </span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I don't want to use any extra external plugin and library.

Comment: Check the library documentation.
https://github.com/Gillardo/bootstrap-ui-datetime-picker

Comment: @Rafee I tried. Could you make demo example snippet?

Comment: Can you see `dateFormat: 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'` in `datetime-picker.js` file. Its already there.

Comment: @Rafee I tried and when I merging in my project it is not working.

Comment: And out of your project? Is it work as you expect?

Comment: @MoshFeu http://embed.plnkr.co/MtQK3wsHtf1hy1F9A5rg/ It is using directive, So I don't want to use directive. I want only javascript code. That's why it is not working

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) plugin?

Comment: @MoshFeu Yes I want to implement same thing without using any plugin. My main objective is I want to select date and time together with existing code.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.. You want a datetimepicker without a plugin? A. Why? B. So what is the issue? Have you started to write any code and you stuck with something?

Comment: @MoshFeu . Now I am selecting separately date and time. When  I using this http://embed.plnkr.co/MtQK3wsHtf1hy1F9A5rg/ code without directive then it is not working. Mean javascript code is not reflecting.

Comment: Why aren't you using directive? This is the wat you should use it. Is your application AngularJS?

Comment: @MoshFeu. Yes my application in angularJs. First I want to try with plain javacsript. Because my application will move angular4. That's wat I want to use javascript only. It will usefull in future also

Comment: Have you started to implement something?

Comment: I implemented separately. Not combined